# Trigger river update elasticsearch

Tags: rest, full-text-search, nosql, search-engine, elasticsearch

I have an elastic search river setup using the jdbc river plugin, that just does a simple select * from and indexes that table.

But I would like to be able to trigger the river on demand via the API as well as at a standard time interval, so that I can have it index a document when its inserted into this table.

Anybody know if theres anyway to do this at present?

i.e. 
`/_river/my_river/_refresh`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a good way for you to trigger the JDBC River into indexing your specific updated document in real time,  and I'm not sure it's meant to be used for that anyways.

Instead of triggering the JDBC river to index your document, why don't you just index the document from the update code?

The JDBC river is a great way to feed in large streams of data,  and there is [documentation for maintaining coherency with the polling](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc).  but I don't think there is an easy to meet your real time requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion. You are very welcome for giving feedback, please join the elasticsearch community. I will open an issue for triggering a fetch at https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/issues

Comment: This is very helpful information (especially the issue link), but it should probably be a comment on the original post as opposed to an actual "answer" to the question because no solution to the problem was provided. Thanks!

Comment: (I realise this is old, but still) Furthermore, it would have been helpful to post the comment _after_ creating the issue, so that the link could have been the actual issue, instead of forcing people to search for it to check the status.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are struggling with the classic "[push vs. pull](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/keeping-datastore-and-index-in-sync-Push-Vs-Pull-best-approach-td4032591.html)" indexing problem. Rivers are designed to pull data out of the database at an interval. They're easy to set up, but like all things in computer science, they are a trade-off. Specifically, you lose real-time indexing. A river that you can trigger might be the best of both worlds, or it might inundate your server with a lot of unnecessary traffic (i.e. why do "SELECT * ..." when you know exactly which document was updated?).

If you have a real-time indexing requirement (like I did), you "push" your updates into Elasticsearch. You just need to write an Elasticsearch client that will deliver your updated records to Elasticsearch as they are saved. FWIW, I solved this problem by firing messages on a service bus, and a service waiting on the other end retrieved the entity from SQL and indexed it. Once you have that infrastructure, it's not a big deal to write a small app to do an initial import of SQL data or create a scheduled job to index data.

Answer (score -1):

alernative would be use logstash with jdbc plugin

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html

1. download logstash
2. install input-jdbc-plugin

example config:

```
    input {
            jdbc {
                    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"
                    jdbc_user => "user"
                    jdbc_driver_library => "/home/logstash/lib/ojdbc6.jar"
                    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
                    statement => "select * from events where update_date > :sql_last_value order by update_date"
                    last_run_metadata_path => "run_metadata_event.log"
                    schedule => "* * * * *"
                    jdbc_password => "password"
            }
    }
    # The filter part of this file is commented out to indicate that it is
    # optional.
    filter {
           mutate {
                   split => { "field_1" => ";"}

           }
    }

    output {
        elasticsearch {
            #protocol => "http"
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            index => "items"
            document_type => "doc_type"
            document_id => "%{doc_id}"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.